# Unit test javascript, same typeof, same string, but test fail

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, solidity, truffle

I try to do unit test on my truffle react-auth project, on my Authentification.sol contract, but when i register a new user, and log him, i have the same typeof var (string), the same strings, but test does not match.
Btw i try to discover test & truffle

Actual string has 32 length and expected has only 8, i dont really know why.
Method's Contract return me a bytes32.

Thank's as well for help

Link of the test img : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P9cx.jpg || https://prnt.sc/mia1yu

```
var Authentication = artifacts.require("./Authentication.sol");

contract('Authentication', function(accounts) {

  let authenticationInstance;

  it("Should sign up and log in", function() {
    return Authentication.deployed().then((instance) => {
      authenticationInstance = instance;

      return authenticationInstance.signup(web3.utils.fromAscii('testuser'));
    }).then( (result) => {
        assert.equal(result.receipt.status, true, "Transaction is done & success")
        return authenticationInstance.login()
    }).then( (name) => {
      let nameConverted = web3.utils.toAscii(name).toString().trim()
        assert.equal(nameConverted, 'testuser', "User has the good name")
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you compare the length of the strings? Maybe there are hidden characters, like spaces, or worse.

Comment: Well, now Actual has 32 length and expected has only 8, i dont really know why. But when i try to supress white space, it does not work, like i cant suppress that i cant see i guess

Comment: I don't really know this web3 stuff, but when I just googled the `fromAscii` and `toAscii` functions, I saw an example where the hex string had a lot of zeroes at the end. Maybe that's related?

Comment: Just thinking out loud now: 32 is coincidentally 4 times the actual length of 8, and it's also some power of 2, so that could cloud the conclusions. It could be some encoding issue causing a multiplication (like UTF-8 vs UTF-32), or some padding issue, or maybe something else. If you change the test string to something of, say 10 characters, is the other string then still 32 (could be padding), or does it become 40 (could be multiplication / encoding), or another value?

Comment: So i tested that, and with every kind of length 0 to 15 and more, it still 32 length when i get the result, only the expected value length change, nothing else

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. I don't know exactly what the reason is there, but it almost looks like web3 is padding it with some character that is unaffected by trim, like `\0` or so.

Comment: Well, i will investigate more about that, and if i find the solution, i will share it.

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND : the bytes32 returned by the contract gave me : 0x74657374000000... (with 32 "0"), but web3 supress those "0" when converted strings does not pass through the contract, then i have to convert the hexToUTF8. Those "0" of hex strings are not visible while the string does not pass via contract's method.

Comment: You should answer your own question below. :)